# Defining the Log source in Enterprise library logging block

Tags: c#

How can i convert the below piece of code to Enterprise Library Logging block

```
EventLog log = new EventLog();
log.Source = "CTA Repository";             
log.WriteEntry("Test Event", EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

basicaly i am not aware how to give the source "CTA Repository" in Logger.write(....)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to log to the event viewer with Enterprise Library. You can define a event log listener with the source as CTA Repository.

The [hands on labs](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hands-on%20Labs&referringTitle=Home) shows you how to log to the event viewer.